# What's the object in the sky?

Tags: planet, amateur-observing, identify-this-object

Days before, I saw this pic. I don't know what it is.

Edit: This pic was taken by a Taoist at an ancient ruins in Mongolia on 2012-07-15 04:12 UTC+8 (day break). He said it looked strange.

[image: Lights in cloudy evening sky]

Edit: I installed Stellarium, changed the time to 2012-07-15 04:12 UTC+8, and faced east. It seems to be the Moon.

[image: It seems the Moon.]

Comment: To me this just looks like an overexposed picture of the Moon in conjunction with a bright star/planet.

Comment: What was your exact location (including country)? What direction were you looking in? What time was it? Did the object move, and if so, how? (give plenty of detail). How long could you see it for? Did it change in appearance? **Please [edit] your answer** to provide this information, otherwise your question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: @Cendolt that's a helpful edit, thanks! It's better to use Stack Exchange's imgur utility to embed the image than to keep a hot-link to an external site. That way if/when the link breaks, the image isn't lost: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chGkd.png

Comment: @uhoh Afaik very new users can't embed images into their posts (I am not sure if it is so also on the Space SE).

Comment: @peterh Cendolt has 63 reputation, I think you only need 10 to do one image. There are higher limits for larger quantities. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/303080 has some info but I haven't found the complete story yet.

Comment: @uhoh Oh, sorry, I will try to remember that next time I have to embed an image.

Comment: More info added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The photo shows a conjunction of the Moon and Jupiter.
A few hours later, observers in Europe
([APOD](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap120720.html),
[virtualtelescope.eu](https://www.virtualtelescope.eu/2012/08/25/jupiter-occultation-by-the-moon-14-july-2012/))
saw the Moon pass directly in front of Jupiter, an event called an occultation.

Stellarium shows Venus and Aldebaran below them, but in the photo they are probably behind a cloud.
Capella is visible at far left, slightly higher than the Moon.

Comment: Nicely done! Beautiful photos in the links too